# using django cleaned data pop to remove data before commit to db

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a form with a select list.

When the user selects a value of 8888 or 9999 from the `award_grant_type` select list, I want some of the data that may or may not exist in the form input fields (the user may have entered data into the form text input fields and then selected 8888 or 9999) to be deleted before the form data is commited to the database.

So I have the following model.py code:

```
.....
DISPLAY_ONLY_AWARD_AND_GRANT_DESCRIPTION_WITH_PROMPT = 8888
DISPLAY_ONLY_AWARD_AND_GRANT_DESCRIPTION_WITHOUT_PROMPT = 9999
.....

AWARD_GRANT_TYPES = (
    (SELECT_AWARD_AND_GRANT_TYPE, _('Select Type')),
    (AWARD, _('Award')),
    (GRANT, _('Grant')),
    (TRAVEL_GRANT, _('Travel Grant')),
    (OTHER_AWARD, _('Other Award')),
    (OTHER_GRANT, _('Other Grant')),
    (WRITE_MY_OWN_AWARD_AND_GRANT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, _('Write my own Type description')),  #7777
    (DISPLAY_ONLY_AWARD_AND_GRANT_DESCRIPTION_WITH_PROMPT, _('Display only Description with prompt')),  #8888
    (DISPLAY_ONLY_AWARD_AND_GRANT_DESCRIPTION_WITHOUT_PROMPT, _('Display only Description without prompt')) #9999
)

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
language_version = models.ForeignKey('LanguageVersion')
award_grant_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=AWARD_GRANT_TYPES, default=SELECT_AWARD_AND_GRANT_TYPE, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
award_grant_type_description = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
award_grant_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
award_grant_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=5000)
```

Here is my forms.py clean code that should remove the `award_grant_type_description` and `award_grant_date` fields when the user has selected 8888 or 9999 from the select list `award_grant_type` before being committed to the db:

```
def clean(self):

    cd_agdf = super(AwardGrantDetailsForm, self).clean()

    if 'award_grant_type' in cd_agdf:
        if cd_agdf['award_grant_type'] == '':
            self._errors['award_grant_type'] = self.error_class([_("You must select a Type.")])

        elif cd_agdf['award_grant_type'] == 8888 or cd_agdf['award_grant_type'] == 9999:
            #  remove the entered values when the award grant type only requires minimum data.
            self.cleaned_data.pop('award_grant_type_description', None)
            self.cleaned_data.pop('award_grant_date', None)
        else:
            ....
    return cd_agdf
```

**Can anyone point out what I have done incorrectly?** The `award_grant_type_description` and `award_grant_date` are not removed before the form data is committed to the db.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

**This issue only occurs when the existing record is updated.** A new record removes the data as required before the form is saved to the db. When an existing record has a date field as part of the db record and the `award_grant_type` is changed from say 1 to 8888 or 9999, then the `award_grant_date` is NOT removed from the db. I cannot figure out why.

**2nd EDIT**

**I have posted a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801530/using-django-cleaned-data-to-reset-data-before-commit-to-db).**

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure `clean` is getting called? Are the relevant `if` statements being evaluated correctly? The only potential issue I can see is that you pop from `self.cleaned_data` but return `cd_agdf`; those *should* both be references to the same thing, but maybe change to use `cd_agdf` throughout, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made the changes but I now realise that the issue only occurs to an existing record - refer to edit / update in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this issue out.

When I wrap the values in quotation marks, the issue is resolved.

Here is the example code I used that works:

```
 elif cd_agdf['award_grant_type'] == '8888' or cd_agdf['award_grant_type'] == '9999':
```

I hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `self.cleaned_data` to `cd_agdf`. Dictionary, that method `clean` returns, will be used as `cleaned_data`. You popped items from `self.cleaned_data`, but returned not changed `cd_ahdf`. This is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) (see last step starting with "The form's subclass...").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made the changes but I now realise that the issue only occurs to an existing record - refer to edit / update in post.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the edit only: there is a fight over what the data means.

**Form validation** happens first, its purpose is to parse the submitted data, clean it up and point any error in the data. The result of this step should be the cleaned up, canonical form of the data.

Then **action**: if valid, form is acted upon. You interpret that data to take appropriate action. Here, writing it to a database.

Your two steps disagree on the meaning of data. Validation removes `award_grant_type_description` and `award_grant_date` from the final data to mean *“blank out those fields”*. Then, the action interprets missing data as *“leave that field as it is”* (that's what the default `ModelForm.save()` does).

Your choice: either conform to `ModelForm`'s convention and set the fields to `None` instead of removing them, or override your form's `save()` so it interprets missing data as *“remove from object”*. Unless I had a good reason to alter ModelForm's semantics, I'd go with setting the fields to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `self.cleaned_data.pop()`
do `cd_agdf.pop()` as you are assigning `cd_agdf` to `superclass`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made the changes but I now realise that the issue only occurs to an existing record - refer to edit / update in post.